# ASPNET Owin Logon - Redirect to Azure Front Door instead of Back Door

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, redirect, owin

We are encountering an issue with owin logon redirecting to the Azure back door instead of the front door. The front door uri is obtained via headers (x-header proto etc.) but it is unclear how to force `ASP/OWIN` to make use of the headers when constructing redirect urls and the "RedirectTo" url parameter.

We could add some code to manually create a url using the x-headers but hope to find a simpler more global solution. Ideally `C#` > `Http.Context.Current.Request` would give `Uri` to the front door, but sadly not.

Below is a code extract. The `ctx.RedirectUri` contains back door url but should contain a front door url. We can find solution for .net core but not for asp/mvc.

Help appreciated.

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
                {
                    if (!IsApiRequest(ctx.Request))
                    {
                        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                    }
                },
```

...

```
        });
```

Comment: I realise this is a very old question, but I've just hit a similar issue. Did you ever find a good solution?

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't figure out how to make that work using OIDC, but for anyone else facing the problem, I found another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73964176/13153